# Generate HTML Table from textarea data with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I want to make a Table generator in PHP which will take each new line in a textarea form field and count each line as a new table cell.  Each textarea will count as a new table column.

So based on this HTML form below it has 4 textarea fields which would result in a table with 4 columns `<tr>`

```
<form action="" id="tablegenform" method="post">  
<textarea name="table-column[]">Enter table column row cell data on each line</textarea>
<textarea name="table-column[]">Enter table column row cell data on each line</textarea>
<textarea name="table-column[]">Enter table column row cell data on each line</textarea>
<textarea name="table-column[]">Enter table column row cell data on each line</textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

The part which makes it a little more difficult for me to wrap my head around in the code is that each new line  item in the textarea is a new table row.

My first approach was something like this...

```
$tableColumnsData = isset($_POST['table-column'])?$_POST['table-column']:"";

foreach($tableColumnsData as $columnKey => $columns){

    // turns each new line in textarea into array item
    $columnRowItems = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $columns));

    // $columnRowItems now holds each row item for that column in an array

    // this is where my logic breaks
    // I need to generate a table row and populate the 4 columns on each row
    // instead my code makes a new column for each items in textarea 
    // and only 4 rows instead of 4 columns and unlimited rows

    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($columnRowItems as $tkey => $tval){
        echo '<td>'.$tval.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

How can I re-write the PHP to work the way I described.

Each textarea field is a Table column

Each line on the textarea is a new row in that column

Comment: Can you be certain that each textarea gets entered the same amount of rows? If not: How should such a case be handled? empty rows at beginning? empty rows at end? error message and no table at all?

Comment: I just copied your code and it looks like it is working. I don't see anything wrong with it, besides missing an `echo '<table>';` at the top. Just to be sure, each textarea is a row, and each line in the textarea is a column, is that right?

Comment: @Andrew Reading the last 2 lines of his question I think it's supposed to be the other way around - that's exactly the problem OP seems to be having.

Comment: @ccKep Oh I see, in the beginning he said each line would be a new table cell which usually means column but now that I read it carefully I think you are right.

Comment: @ccKep you are right.  I posted an answer below with a new working version.  Not sure if it is the best way but it works how I need it to now thanks guys.  Also to answer about empty items, it simply will generate an empty table cell <td> for those items so that the order of things stays correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working now with this code....welcome to improvements though!

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['table-column'])) {

  $tableColumnsData = $_POST['table-column'];

  $columnCounts = array();
  $tableDataArray = array();

  echo '
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>';
  // get count of rows from each column to determine highest number so our 
  // table will have this many rows
  foreach($tableColumnsData as $columnKey => $rows){
      echo "<th>$columnKey</th>";
      $columnRowData = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $rows));
      $columnCounts[] = count($columnRowData);
      $tableDataArray[] = $columnRowData;
  }

  $numberOfTableColumns = count($tableColumnsData);
  $numberOfTableRows = max($columnCounts);


  echo '</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';
  for ($rowCounter = 0; $rowCounter < $numberOfTableRows; $rowCounter++) {
      echo '<tr>';
      for ($columnCounter = 0; $columnCounter < $numberOfTableColumns; $columnCounter++) {
          if(isset($tableDataArray[$columnCounter][$rowCounter]) && $tableDataArray[$columnCounter][$rowCounter] != ''){
              echo '<td>'.$tableDataArray[$columnCounter][$rowCounter].'</td>';
          }else{
              echo '<td></td>';
          }
      }
      echo '</tr>';
  }
  echo '
    </tbody>
  </table>
  ';

}
?>

<form action="" id="tablegenform" method="post">  
<textarea name="table-column[col1]">
  Enter one row on each line for this table column.
</textarea>
<textarea name="table-column[col2]">
  Enter one row on each line for this table column.
  Here's another Line.
</textarea>
<textarea name="table-column[col3]">
  Enter one row on each line for this table column.
</textarea>
<textarea name="table-column[col4]">
  Enter one row on each line for this table column.
  This is a line.
  Here's another row cell.
</textarea>
<textarea name="table-column[col5]">
  Enter one row on each line for this table column.
</textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Results in this output:

```html
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th><th>col3</th><th>col4</th><th>col5</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody><tr><td>  Enter one row on each line for this table column.</td><td>  Enter one row on each line for this table column.</td><td>  Enter one row on each line for this table column.</td><td>  Enter one row on each line for this table column.</td><td>  Enter one row on each line for this table column.</td></tr><tr><td></td><td>  Here's another Line.</td><td></td><td>  This is a line.</td><td>Again</td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>  Here's another row cell.</td><td>and again</td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>again</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
<form action="" id="tablegenform" method="post">  
<textarea name="table-column[col1]">
  Enter one row on each line for this table column.
</textarea>
<textarea name="table-column[col2]">
  Enter one row on each line for this table column.
  Here's another Line.
</textarea>
<textarea name="table-column[col3]">
  Enter one row on each line for this table column.
</textarea>
<textarea name="table-column[col4]">
  Enter one row on each line for this table column.
  This is a line.
  Here's another row cell.
</textarea>
<textarea name="table-column[col5]">
  Enter one row on each line for this table column.
</textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I really wanted to improve this because I felt like 3 loops was surely too much, but it's pretty brilliant actually. my only contributions are to 1) rename `$columns` to `$rows` for context, 2) get rid of notices by skipping the script if form not posted, 3) you declared `$columnKey` but never used it, so I added an associative index to the form for use with a table header, 4) semantically complete html table with border, 5) laid out the pre-filled textarea example data clearer, 6) delete some unused arrays. feel free to rollback

Comment: @JeffPuckettII thanks for feedback.  I just kept tweaking it until the output looked correct so theres surely room to improve as you mentioned a few good ideas thanks.  My final solution also shows a dropdown with number and you simply select a number which then generates the textareas so user can set the number of columns with that and then inside of each texarea will be the rows for that column.  I plan to use in a popup modal window for a shortcode editor button in WordPress edit screens for quickly creating tables by pasting table row data into a column